# How to start verifying this trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I start verifying the identity $\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=\frac18(1-\cos(4x))$?

I'm very new to trigonometry, so there's probably a topic I've learned and then forgotten. I tried a lot of things, no matter how hopeless they looked, but the three main attempts were distributing $\frac{1}{8}$, trying to get the equation to cosx instead of $\cos(4x)$, and trying to use a Pythagorean Identity on the left side of the equation. None of these techniques got me anywhere, as far as I could see.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We are happy to help you as long as you provide your attempts at trying to solve the proposed exercise. Can you tell us where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Combine $\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin^2(\beta)=(1-\cos(2\beta))/2$ for appropiate $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Please show your own attempts in future questions

Comment: I'm very new to trigonometry, so there's probably a topic I've learned and then forgotten.  I tried a lot of things, no matter how hopeless they looked, but the three main attempts were distributing 1/8, trying to get the equation to cosx instead of cos4x, and trying to use a Pythagorean Identity on the left side of the equation. None of these techniques got me anywhere, as far as I could see.

Comment: Rewriting $\cos(4x)$ in terms of $\cos x$ (or $\cos x$ and $\sin x$) seems like a viable strategy. If you don't know the formula for $4$ times the angle, try the double angle formula ($4x$ is two times $2x$).

Comment: I tried that, @DavidK, but it didn't work - I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Instead of summarizing your attempts in the comments, edit your post to show us what you did try - and maybe we can spot a mistake!

Comment: Note that the left-hand side is some multiple of $\sin^2 2x$.

Comment: You can prove it theoretically with the relation of trigonometric functions to exponential functions... If you use this in combination with the trigonometric Pythagoras and the binomial formulas, the proof goes very quickly...

Answer (score 3):

Using double-angle identity $\cos 2x=\cos^2 x - \sin^2x$ , we can obtain that $2\cos^2x=\cos 2x+1, 2\sin^2 x=1-\cos 2x$

Thus, $ \cos^2x \cdot \sin^2 x=\frac{1}{4}(1-\cos^22x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 2x=\frac{1}{8}(1-\cos 4x)$

Answer (score 0):

If you have a trigonometric identity that you need to prove, a good step would be to go through the relationship of the trigonometric functions to other functions and see if any of these relationships can be useful.

For example, if you do this, you can discover that the proof quickly goes through the relation to expotential functions $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2 \cdot \mathrm{i}}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2}$.

If you use this in combination with the the binomial formulas, the proof goes very quickly:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sin^{2}(x) \cdot \cos^{2}(x) &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
(\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x))^{2} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x)) \quad\mid\quad \sin(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2 \cdot \mathrm{i}} \wedge \cos(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2}\\
\left( \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2 \cdot \mathrm{i}} \cdot \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2} \right)^{2} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\left( \frac{\left( e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right) \cdot \left( e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right)}{4 \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right)^{2} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\frac{\left(\left( e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right) \cdot \left( e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right)\right)^{2}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x)) \quad\mid\quad \text{use the third binomial formula}\\
\frac{\left( e^{2 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-2 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right)^{2}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x)) \quad\mid\quad \text{use the second binomial formula}\\
\frac{e^{4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - 2 \cdot e^{2 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} \cdot e^{-2 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\frac{e^{4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - 2 \cdot 1 + e^{-4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\frac{e^{4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - 2 + e^{-4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\frac{-2}{-16} + \frac{e^{4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{-16} &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\frac{1}{8} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{e^{4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-4 \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2} \right) &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x)) \quad\mid\quad \sin(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} - e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2 \cdot \mathrm{i}} \wedge \cos(x) = \frac{e^{x \cdot \mathrm{i}} + e^{-x \cdot \mathrm{i}}}{2}\\
\frac{1}{8} \cdot \left( 1 - \cos(4 \cdot x) \right) &= \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x)) \quad \square\\
&\Rightarrow \sin^{2}(x) \cdot \cos^{2}(x) = \frac{1}{8} \cdot(1 - \cos(4 \cdot x))\\
\end{align*}
$$